# Boolean kotlin/java NullPointerException

Tags: java, kotlin, boolean

I have a question about this code that combines Kotlin and Java. When I run the main method, it works well. However, when I run it in debug mode, I encounter a NullPointerException with it.adminRole but not with it.function. I need an explanation for this.

```java
public class Role {

    public String function;

    public Boolean adminRole;

    public Role(){

    }
    public Role(String function, Boolean adminRole) {
        this.function = function;
        this.adminRole = adminRole;
    }

}
```

```java
public class User {

    public String name;
    public String surname;

    public Role role;

    public User(){

    }
    public User(String name, String surname, Role role) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

```kotlin
fun User.getUser(): TestUser? =
    this.role?.let {
        TestUser(
            adminRole = it.adminRole, //in debug mode i get NullPointerException( i want to understand why??)
            function = it.function, //in debug mode i get null value
        )
    }

fun main() {
    val user = User().apply {
        role = Role()
    }
    user.getUser()

}

data class TestUser(
    val adminRole: Boolean? = null,
    val function: String? = null,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Java object reference types, like Boolean, are initialized to null by default.  If you wish it to have a non-null initial value you should say so in the constructor.

I'd try this:

```
public class Role {

    public final String function;

    public final Boolean adminRole;

    public Role() {
        this("", Boolean.False);
    }

    public Role(String function, Boolean adminRole) {
        this.function = function;
        this.adminRole = adminRole;
    }
}
```

It's not recommended to make public variables mutable.  I marked both as final to prevent modification after initialization.

I would also recommend that your default constructors call the full constructor with default values spelled out.  It makes your intention clearer.  It implies that you thought about your default constructor instead of allowing an IDE to auto generate it for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in my case, the API I call can respond with a null value in the adminRole field. However, I don't understand why I get a NullPointerException with the Boolean type and not the String type. I want to handle the null value of Boolean but i want explanation

Comment: I only have control over the Kotlin part of the code; the Java code is beyond my control.

Comment: No control?  Then you're screwed.  I see problems with this Java code.  You will have the same problem with the String type.  Perhaps the code you wrote doesn't expose it yet.

Comment: If the API might have a null value for the field in the Java class, you need to defensively treat it as nullable. Kotlin doesn’t enforce null checks for nullable Java fields and return values.